# connect to mysql using c++

Tags: c++, mysql, c

is it possible to connect to an mysql database and issue queries using c++?
i found some sample code from the internet but they all use mysql! so u need to install mysql first on the computer.
what i want is to use a program from different locations where i don't have mysql installed to access a remote mysql database.
is this possible?

Comment: If your remote host is configured accordingly then it is possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the samples you've seen requires to install **mysql libraries**, not a **mysql database**. This is an important difference.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. It is abundantly clear what the guy wants, he just didn't provide the technical detail necessary that he probably doesn't even know that we need to know.

Answer (score 3):

Warren Young has made a C++ library call Mysql++ you can find more info at:
[Mysql++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/)

You could also take a look at: [libmysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/building-clients.html)

Comment: Thanks for the mention!  The original poster's confusion is that in the past, the easiest way to get the MySQL C API libraries that the various C++ wrappers for it depend on is to install the MySQL server on the development machine.  A few months ago, they broke it out for the first time, calling it Connector/C.  I just barely tested it with MySQL++ and it works fine.  I just haven't gotten around to updating the MySQL++ pages and docs to talk about this option yet.

Comment: @WarrenYoung excellent wrapper!  where can one find info regarding error handling?  specifically: what is the function for mysqlpp::Query error numbers?  i can get error message using query.error() but am having a hard time establishing when an error is NULL (i.e. after an insert)

Answer (score 1):

You need mysql client libraries. You don't have to have mysql server installed. Details depend on your environment/packaging/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try `libmysql`. You would probably need to write your own C++ wrapper for `libmysql` calls but it's worth it. And, yes, you don't need to have local server installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [MySQL Connector C++](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Connector_C%2B%2B) to connect to a database.  This is on Windows XP and Vista.  I'm using it with Visual Studio 2008.

Your program creates a connection by specifying the URL to the computer where the database resides.  Thus many instances of the application can access a remote database.