# How to connect to mysql using wxwidget?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Hello I am new to wxwidgets and dont know how to connect to the mysql database. I was wondering if any one could give me some hint or simple program sample. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You connect to a mysql db in just the same was as from any C++ program.  wxWidgets is irrelevant.

There are lots of ways to achieve what you want.  You will have to hunt around to find what works for you.  Here is a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904767/connect-to-mysql-using-c) to get you started.