# Sending from C++ to PHP / HTML

Tags: php, c++, mysql

I would like to send data from my C++ app to a database via HTML form or just by and address in PHP script like `index.php?mydata=something`. I'm trying to do this because sending an email from C++ was to hard for a beginner like me. I just want to send one string or if it's possible, a file.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Or if someone can guide me how to connect directly to the MySQL and insert the data in a specified table i woudl be more than grateful ! : )

EDIT2: I found the mysql api and have all the libraries and mysql header but i have problems with connecting to the DB. error: unresolved external symbol _mysql_init@4 referenced in function _main code : pastebin.com/TLjDRJXD

Comment: Why not direct to the database, via the databases API?

Comment: because i'm new to c++ and didnt know there is something like that

Comment: possible duplicate of [connect to mysql using c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904767/connect-to-mysql-using-c)

Answer (score 1):

use JSON. It has native support in newer versions of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

C API for MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/dynindex-cfunction.html

http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Category:C

C++ API for MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html

http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Connector_C%2B%2B

There are many more, e.g. C++ wrappers for the C API:

http://mysqlcppapi.sourceforge.net/

Comment: i found it but i have problems with connecting to the DB. I have the mysql headers and libraries but theres an error: unresolved external symbol _mysql_init@4 referenced in function _main code : http://pastebin.com/TLjDRJXD

Comment: @shym see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108740/why-simple-mysql-code-compiles-standalone-but-not-in-project

Comment: the thing is that I had other errors but now i linked everything properly but it still doesent work : / i linked libmysql.lib and the whole folder with headers in MySQL community Server but still doesen't work : /

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it might be best to do this with a simple PHP API. This way you can be sure to have a clean and secure connection between your C++ app and the PHP app.

You can Google around to find lots of examples and [tutorials](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/).

Answer (score 0):

The better way is a PHP API but if you are curious you can use [IndyProject](http://www.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may find these useful:

[What C++ library should I use to implement a HTTP client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822581/what-c-library-should-i-use-to-implement-a-http-client)

[High-level HTTP client library for native C/C++ in Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124129/high-level-http-client-library-for-native-c-c-in-win32)

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html

Basically you can use any C++ http client to send GET/POST requests to your PHP page.